# How to add custom fields in admin order page in woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a plugin for WooComerce. I have to add a custom section in WooComerce order admin page, below order items section. My section will contain few text boxes and drop-downs and a button. On button click i will call a web service and pass parameters to it from my fields filled in section.

How should i start this i mean for designing is there any hook of WC order page through which i can add my section fields etc. or should i use meta boxes? Whats the best way.

I found woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta hook but it didnt work for me.

Comment: why or how it did not work?

Comment: @Reigel It didnt work the way i wanted. I want a new section under order items section, but using this hook its coming inside order items section..

Comment: if you mean below the whole box of "Order Items". You will need to create a new meta box..

Comment: @Reigel Yes i need it below whole box of "order items".. i have found this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179529/how-to-add-custom-fields-for-woocommerce-order-page-admin but em not sure if its the right way?

Comment: yes... that should be your starting point... you may need to change `'side'` to `'normal'`...

Comment: @Reigel i changed it to normal now its coming under custom fields box. any way i can set it under order items?

Comment: When you add meta boxes using `add_meta_boxes` it follows the same order: last added, last shown. But each registered user that can access to orders backend, can drag and drop and reorder the meta boxes…