# Display an estimated delivery date range based on WooCommerce cart item stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-variations

I am trying to output an estimated delivery date in the cart based on the stock status of the products in the cart.

I was a little bit successful but now I am stuck.

This is what I have written so far. It goes in the function.php file

```
function lieferzeit() {
    
    global $woocommerce;
        $cart_items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
        foreach ($cart_items as $variation) {
            $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
         $variation_obj = new WC_Product_variation($variation_id);
         $stock = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();
        }
echo $stock; //outputs the in stock amount successfully

}
        

add_filter ( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'lieferzeit');
```

Now I am trying to add the estimated date but here I am stuck

```
function lieferzeit() {
    
    global $woocommerce;
        $cart_items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
        foreach ($cart_items as $variation) {
            $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
         $variation_obj = new WC_Product_variation($variation_id);
         $stock = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();
        }
       
        for ($i=0; $i < count($stock) ; $i++) {
            echo "Voraussichtliche Lieferung Date! ";
            
            
        }
}

add_filter ( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'lieferzeit');
```

Here the date output have to be defined. From today +1 day until from today +4 days. But I don't have an idea how to manage that.
The best output would be this format:

**Estimated shipping Fri. 14.7 - Wed. 19.7**

I am not even sure if

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($stock) ; $i++) {
```

is the right way to go.

I do have two types of products, one can be shipped within 1-4 days and the other is within 14-21 days. Now is second problem. When both types are in the cart the higher shipping time should be selected.

Are there some ideas?

---

**Update:**

The code should check the stock quantity of each item in the cart.
If all items have a stock quantity greater than 0 it should echo an estimated shipping time of 1 to 4 working days given as a date.

If there is one item in cart with a stock quantity of 0 or below it should echo an estimate shipping time of 14 - 21 working days given as a date. Even if all the other items in the cart have a stock quantity greater than 0.

Working days should be monday until friday. Very neat would be if the code recognizes holidays too e.g. christmas, new year etc..

Thanks

> The solution from LoicTheAztec works perfect. Now I tried to add some more option to it.

It would be nice if the output of `function lieferzeit()` would be displayed in the admin order details page.
To create a custom admin panel in the sidebar I found

```
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_meta_boxes' );
function add_meta_boxes()
{
    add_meta_box( 
        'woocommerce-order-my-custom', 
        __( 'Order Custom' ), 
        'order_my_custom', 
        'shop_order', 
        'side', 
        'default' 
    );
}
 
function order_my_custom()
{
   echo $lieferzeit;
}
```

[from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179529/how-to-add-custom-fields-for-woocommerce-order-page-admin)

This works so far and there is a Order Custom tab in the admin page. Now I tried to store the output of `function lieferzeit()` in a variable.

```
$from = str_replace($days_en, $days_ge, $from);
$to   = str_replace($days_en, $days_ge, $to);

$lieferzeit = array($from, $to);
```

But it seems that `function add_meta_boxes()` and `function order_my_custom()` doen't know nothing of the variable `$lieferzeit`.

Is there another way to store and recall the output of `function lieferzeit()` ?

Comment: I have seen your question about the products only yet. Stackoverflow is a little bit chaotic :)

I use both single and variable products. But your solution is working very good for both types!

Comment: **I have updated my code** regarding simple and variable product stock… **It should work now** …*You could also use stock status `if($product_obj->get_stock_status() == 'instock'){` or `if($product_obj->get_stock_status() == 'outofstock'){`* … I hope this time is OK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 4** *(on September 2018)*

The code below, will check the stock quantity of each item in the cart.

1) If all cart items are "in stock" it will echo an estimated shipping time of 1 to 4 working days given as a date.

2) If one cart items is "out of stock" it will echo an estimated shipping time of 14 to 21 working days given as a date.

**But I will not recognize holidays**

Here is that code:

```
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'lieferzeit');
function lieferzeit() {

    $all_items_in_stock = true; // initializing

    // Iterating through cart items (to get the stock info)
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        // The cart item stock quantity
        $stock = $cart_item['data']->get_stock_quantity();

        if( $stock <= 0 ){
            // if an item is out of stock
            $all_items_in_stock = false;
            break; // We break the loop
        }
    }

    // Items "in stock" (1 to 4 week days)
    if( $all_items_in_stock ){
        for( $start=0, $count=-1 ; $count < 4; $start++ ){
            $weekdays = date('w', strtotime("+$start days"));
            if( $weekdays > 0 && $weekdays < 6 ){
                $count++;
            echo date('D j (w)', strtotime("+$start days")).', ';
                if($count == 1){
                    $from = date('D. j/n', strtotime("+$start days") );
                } elseif($count == 4) {
                    $to = date('D. j/n', strtotime("+$start days") );
                }
            }
        }
    } else { // 1 is Items Out of stock (14 to 21 week days)
        for( $start=0, $count=-1 ; $count < 21; $start++ ){
            $weekdays = date('w', strtotime("+$start days"));
            if( $weekdays > 0 && $weekdays < 6 ){
                $count++;
                if($count == 14){
                    $from = date('D. j/n', strtotime("+$start days") );
                } elseif($count == 21) {
                    $to = date('D. j/n', strtotime("+$start days") );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ## TRANSLATION ##

    // DAYS IN ENGLISH (Source)
    $days_en = array('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri');

    // TRANSLATE the DAYS in GERMAN (replacement)
    $days_ge = array('Mmm','Ttt','Www','Thh','Fff');

    $from = str_replace( $days_en, $days_ge, $from );
    $to = str_replace( $days_en, $days_ge, $to );

    ## OUTPUT ##

    echo "<br><br>Estimated shipping $from - $to";
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec,
thank you so much for your help!! Thats unbelievable. I don't know how many days I would have spent on this without your help. 

The only thing which seems more complicated that I thought it would be, is to get an output in German. 

I like this format `('D, j.n.', strtotime("+$start days"))` a lot. But a simple add of `setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");` won't work. And replace all the strtotime with strftime doesn't work too. Even with changing the dateformat to `%a, %d.%m.`

Comment: There is something I have discovered only now. I thought it works with single products. It does only when the single product is out of stock. For a single product which is in stock and has the short delivery time it only shows the long shipping time. 

I tried to add this to the beginning, but it didn't help. 
`$simple_id = $cart_item['simple_id'];
        $simple_obj = new WC_Product_simple($simple_id);
        $stock_simple = $simple_obj->get_stock_quantity();`

And then I added fellowing.

`if( $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity() <= 0 xor $simple_obj->get_stock_quantity() <= 0){`

Comment: Its working perfectly now! I've made a little change, so that products with less than 0 stock quantity are in the condition too. 
I changed 
`if( 0 == $stock )` to `if( $stock  <= 0 )`